# PayPal mass pay transaction fee - Is there any other way to do payment with PayPal without transaction fee?

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox, payment, paypal-adaptive-payments

In my scenario I have to pay my employees using their PayPal email id and i am doing this with **PayPal Mass Pay**. Problem i am facing is that 2% transaction fee deduct from merchant account. I have to do this without transaction fee and user interaction. **Is there any other way to do payment with PayPal without transaction fee?**

I have tried PayPal Adaptive Payments but not suitable for my scenario.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's better suited for PayPal support than SO.

Answer (score 0):

If you send cash funds (PayPal or bank account balance) using a "Personal" or what's now called "Friends and Family" payment, then there is no fee.

This can be achieved using the [Adaptive Payments API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/), specifically the [Pay API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/) with the paymentType parameter set to PERSONAL.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "actionType=PAY&paymentType=PERSONAL&senderEmail=xx@x.com&cancelUrl=xxx.com&currencyCode=USD&receiverList.receiver(0).email=xxx@x.com&receiverList.receiver(0).amount=10.00&requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=en_US&returnUrl=xx.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "X-Paypal-Security-Userid: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$headers[] = "X-Paypal-Security-Password: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$headers[] = "X-Paypal-Security-Signature: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$headers[] = "X-Paypal-Request-Data-Format: NV";
$headers[] = "X-Paypal-Response-Data-Format: NV";
$headers[] = "X-Paypal-Application-Id: APP-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
echo $result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: @AndrewAngell according this code receiver account pay transaction fee. any solution for that no one have to pay fee?